# Simple loop bug which i forgot

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I want to build a list. The list have the number of values asked for from the user, and can't pass the limit and can't repeat, but I don't know where my error is. The program doesn't build the list by the way I want to. It's a bit hard to explain, but run the code by yourself with the attributes:

```
class Mundo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.existValues = list()
        self.world = self.grid()
        self.blues = self.blue()
        print(f"Map: {self.world}\n"
              f"Exist Values: {self.existValues}\n"
              f"Blue values: {self.blues}")
        # self.theArray = [[self.world, ], [self.world, ]]

    def grid(self):
        while True:
            self.size = input("Size of Map: ")
            if self.size.isnumeric() and int(self.size) >= 2:
                self.size = int(self.size)
                intSize = self.size * self.size
                mapH = list()
                gridMap = list()
                for elementos in range(1, intSize + 1):
                    if len(mapH) == self.size - 1:
                        mapH.append(elementos)
                        gridMap.append(mapH)
                        mapH = []
                    else:
                        mapH.append(elementos)
                return gridMap

    def blue(self):
        while True:
            try:
                qt = int(input("How many blues to spawn?"))
            except ValueError:
                continue
            posBlue = list()
            controle = list()
            control = False
            for _ in range(qt):
                while not control:
                    x = rint(1, self.size)
                    y = rint(1, self.size)
                    controle.append([x, y])
                    for elements in controle:
                        if elements in self.existValues:
                            control = True
                        else:
                            posBlue.append([x, y])
                            self.existValues.append([x, y])
                            control = False

            return posBlue
```

If i run the code (being that qt == 2, and self.size == 4 ), one, two or three times the code outputs a list that contains 3 or 2 values, and sometimes 4.

I will run 3 times to show.

Output 1:
[Only 3 values in blues, i asked for 4.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tfp9q.png)

Output 2:
[Only 2, i ask for 4.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRE7D.png)

Output 3:
[Again.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNUL1.png)

I need that output that the user ask.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. For debugging help, you need to provide a [mre] including complete code, example input, expected output, and actual output. You can [edit]. See [ask] if you want more tips.

Comment: "Just run it and see" is not particularly helpful.  Please edit your question to more precisely explain exactly the behavior you see and how that differs from your expectations - preferably in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: I fixed the code and ran it and it seems to sort of work.  The main problem I can see is that you aren't guaranteed to get a unique pair on each iteration, which means you'll end up skipping some, and depending on what the user enters it might not even be possible to get as many unique pairs as they asked for.  I might suggest using `itertools.product` to generate all the possibilities (assuming `size` is always going to be small enough for that to be feasible) and then using `random.choices`.

Comment: I edited the question to be useful to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your code in more of an MRE form:

```
from random import randint


def blue(qt: int, size: int):
    existValues = []
    posBlue = list()
    controle = list()
    for _ in range(qt):
        x = randint(1, 4)
        y = randint(1, 4)
        controle.append([x, y])
        for elements in controle:
            if elements in existValues:
                continue
            else:
                posBlue.append([x, y])
                existValues.append([x, y])

    return posBlue


print(len(blue(2, 4)))    # prints 2 because odds are good of getting 2 uniques
print(len(blue(10, 4)))   # prints 8 because it missed some
print(len(blue(100, 4)))  # prints 16 because that's the maximum number
```

By testing with different quantities, it's easy to see where the problem is -- you're dependent on random chance to generate unique combinations, so there's not a guarantee that each iteration of your `for` loop is going to find a combination that doesn't already exist.

The easy way to do this is to generate an exhaustive list of combinations and then select them randomly:

```
from itertools import product
from random import sample


def blue(qt: int, size: int):
    possibilities = list(product(range(1, size+1), range(1, size+1)))
    return sample(possibilities, qt)


print(len(blue(2, 4)))    # prints 2
print(len(blue(10, 4)))   # prints 10
print(len(blue(100, 4)))  # ValueError: Sample larger than population
```

Note that this raises an exception if `qt` is greater than `size^2`.  You can decide if you want to handle this a different way -- maybe given a sufficiently large quantity repeats are acceptable?  Here's a simple approach to making that fix: multiply `possibilities` by the quantity necessary to ensure that it's at least as big as `qt`.

```
def blue(qt: int, size: int):
    possibilities = list(product(range(1, size+1), range(1, size+1)))
    possibilities *= 1 + (qt - 1) // len(possibilities)
    return sample(possibilities, qt)
```